# how to do it with one SQL query to get the id from table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to do it with one SQL query to get the id from table 1 and verify how many times this ID is in table 2

Comment: Peter next time at least provide some sample data structure and tell us what did you try, please.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT T.ID,COUNT(T.ID)CNTT
  FROM TABLE_1 AS T
  JOIN TABLE_2 AS B ON T.ID=B.ID
  GROUP BY T.ID
```